# Find a doubled value between two columns in the same row

Tags: sql-server, query

We discovered a bug in our program where there are some instances of a doubled value. I am trying to write a query to find all instances of this doubled value.

Right now I am using

```
    WHERE 
(GRIR.ReceivedQty > GRIR.OrderedQty)
```

And this shows any instance where the "Received" is greater than the "Ordered" but it's returning lots of data that I don't need. (e.g. 41 received where 40 ordered, this is fine and non-issue)

How can I compare my Received against Ordered where the Received is exactly double the Ordered value. (e.g. 8 received and 4 ordered)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. Please have a look at: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example). It would help if you add some data and the desired result in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause can include basic math like this, e.g.

```
WHERE GRIR.ReceivedQty = 2.0 * GRIR.OrderedQty;
```

...or...

```
WHERE GRIR.OrderedQty = GRIR.ReceivedQty / 2.0;
```

(And [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b4981f2d6133a7ca5b1e301452849532) demonstrates why `2.0` is more accurate than `2`, assuming your columns are in the `int` family.)

Comment: I like the demonstration of the integer division. Another possible example: using `WHERE GRIR.ReceivedQty / GRIR.OrderedQty = 2` returns one more row ;)

Comment: I would recommend using `2e` or `2e0` (float literals) as opposed to `2.0`. `2.0` is a numeric literal. If both columns are float sql will probably do the right thing, but it can do silly things if one side is numeric/decimal.